# Вычесть значения массивов?

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Есть 1-ый массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date1] => 19.08.2016
            [money] => 500
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date1] => 18.08.2016
            [money] => 800
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date1] => 17.08.2016
            [money] => 1500
        )
```

Из этого массива, нужно вычесть money из второго массива (bouns):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date1] => 19.08.2016
            [bonus] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date1] => 18.08.2016
            [bonus] => 500
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date1] => 17.08.2016
            [bonus] => 0.00
        )
```

Чтобы получилось так:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date1] => 19.08.2016
            [money] => 400
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date1] => 18.08.2016
            [money] => 300
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date1] => 17.08.2016
            [money] => 1500
        )
```

Есть такой цикл, но он не работает:

```
foreach ($arr_money as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($arr_bonus as $k => $v) {
        $arr_money[$key]['money'] -= $v['bonus'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваша ошибка в том, что вы используете двойной цикл там, где можно обойтись одним. Учитывая, что у вас индексы числовые, возможно, будет удобнее пользоваться обычным циклом for, а не foreach.

Comment: А у меня вопрос как так `1500 - 0.00 = 0.00`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$array_money = array(
    array(
        'date1' => '19.23.2016',
        'money' => 500
        ),
    array(
        'date2' => '18.23.2016',
        'money' => 500
    ),
    array(
        'date3' => '17.23.2016',
        'money' => 500
    ),
);

$array_bonus = array(
    array(
        'date1' => '19.23.2016',
        'bonus' => 400
    ),
    array(
        'date2' => '18.23.2016',
        'bonus' => 300
    ),
    array(
        'date3' => '17.23.2016',
        'bonus' => 100
    ),
);

for ($i = count($array_money)-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {

    $array_money[$i]['money'] -= $array_bonus[$i]['bonus'];

}
```

Comment: Есть еще вариант через foreach

    `foreach ($array_money as $key => $value) {
        $array_money[$key]['money'] -= $array_bonus[$key]['bonus'];
      }`